# Github Pages displays embedded YouTube video on one site but not the other, is there a fix for this?

Tags: html, css, github, video, embed

I have one site hosted on Github Pages that successfully embeds a YouTube video.  I'm in the process of building a second site for public release and would like to include an embedded video on this as well.  The embed works locally so I know my code isn't the issue, but Github refuses to display the video on this second site.  More detail below, including specific code.

Site with working Youtube embed: https://greattimeband.github.io
New site (work in progress): https://gr8time.github.io

The old site displays two videos in the lower left, embedded and fully functioning.  The second site does not display the video (just under the carousel up top) but seemingly recognizes the element as existing.  There are a few variables that may be at play here:

Site #1 was built using Webflow and may have some inherent styling or containers that I am unaware of.  I scoured my css for any clues but can't seem to find any.  This embed is also pointing directly to a specific video rather than calling upon the "most recent upload"

Site #2 is being built with Bootstrap. The embed is also calling upon the most recent upload on my channel rather than a specific video (so the site should update itself with each new upload).

Either of these factors may be contributing, but I'm wondering why Github does fine with the first example and not with the second.  I understand Github Pages may not allow embedding of videos at all, which makes the first example even more interesting.  Wondering if there may be an explanation on either side and if my inadvertent success on the first site can be replicated (without using Webflow).

Site #1 embed code (working):

```
    <div class="video-div-block">
    <div class="video-row w-row">
    <div class="column-5 w-col w-col-4">
        <h2 class="heading-2 video">Video</h2>

        <div style="padding-top:56.17021276595745%" class="w-video w-embed">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" 
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4PSGaDSS8A4" frameborder="0" 
        allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>

        <div style="padding-top:56.17021276595745%" class="video w-video w-embed">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" 
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cV4NthqdXRM" frameborder="0" 
        allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
   </div>
   </div>
```

Site #2 embed code (working but not displaying):

```
    <div class="video-container">
    <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries? 
    list=UUJhHaq56JKvZlAQ32OH71nQ&index=0" frameborder="0" 
    allowfullscreen> 
    </iframe>
    </div>
```

The second example displays properly and pulls the correct video locally, but Github refuses to display content.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change iframe src http to https like:

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries? 
    list=UUJhHaq56JKvZlAQ32OH71nQ&index=0" frameborder="0" 
    allowfullscreen>
```